# Converting headphone signals into MP3 using Arduino

Tags: arduino, audio, mp3

For my project, I am looking for a way to take headphone audio signals (from TVs and other appliances), convert them into MP3 and send them over WiFi to a remote device (PC or other) using Arduino UNO and a Wifi Shield.

Any ideas as to a circuit design and required components that would achieve it?

Thanks!

Comment: You're not likely going to be able to do this with an arduino - it's nowhere near fast enough to do mp3 encoding on the fly, and even if you could it is not likely possible you get it to the wifi card fast enough.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [VS1063](http://www.vlsi.fi/en/products/vs1063.html) to do on-the-fly conversion of audio to MP3.  VLSI offer an [eval board](http://www.vlsi.fi/en/support/evaluationboards/vs1053vs8053simpledspboard.html) that you can hook up to a microcontroller, or even a toyduino, to configure and stream from the VS1063.  The pro kit includes all the audio circuitry and connectors.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a different platform, such as a beagle bone or raspberry pi. An Arduino is not going to be powerful enough.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies and insights.

Is there a specific Arduino shield that I can use to convert the audio to MP3 to remove the load from the Arduino? I would then use a WiFi shield to send it over to the other end...

Would that work?